# How to trigger JavaScript when img-tag appears in DOM or src-attribute changes Or: Adding Wheelzoom to h5ai

Tags: javascript, dom

For days now I am trying to figure out something and I can't get it to work - maybe somebody can help.

**My (global) goal: I am trying to add a "zoom by mousewheel" to the image-viewer of the php-web-server-index-tool [h5ai](https://larsjung.de/h5ai/).**

My idea how to do it:
I found the tool "[Wheelzoom](https://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/)" which adds the possibility to zoom to every img-tag on the page without changing the DOM by only doing 2 things:

1. linking to the wheelzoom.js on the page
2. calling "`wheelzoom(document.querySelectorAll('img#pv-content-img'));`" after the page has loaded

With h5ai I can insert JavaScript by placing it in the "ext"-Folder and adding it to the options.json - this adds a script-tag to the header; so no problem to get the wheelzoom.js loaded.

But I am struggling with the command "`wheelzoom(document.querySelectorAll('img#pv-content-img'));`". So far I put it in an extra .js-file, also calling it in the header. But I need it to be triggered more often:

h5ai has always an empty `<div id=pv-overlay>` in the DOM. Only when you click on an image-filename, it fills it with "`<div id=pv-container><img id=pv-content-img src=""...>`", changing the src-attribute of the image by clicking "back/forward".
(You can check out my project [here](https://archiv.wurmweb.at/Nickelsdorf/Kirche%20Katholisch/Nickelsdorf%20-%20KircheKath%20-%201790-1826%20Heiratsbuch/), to see it live)

How do I trigger the wheelzoom-command after the img-tag appears and/or the src-attribute changes? I tried a lot, now something like this:

```
var insertedNodes = [];
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log("Change!"); //here the wheelzoom-function should be triggered
  })
});
observer.observe(document, {
  childList: true
});
```

But with all my trying - either I run into a loop that crashes the site, or it doesn't get triggered at all (like the version above).

Now I wonder: Is my idea possible? Is there a better way without changing the sourcecode of h5ai? When I use the browser-console and type in the command after an image is loaded-it works perfectly!

Thanks for your help!

edit 2022/11/15 - my last version, sadly still not working:

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
    switch (document.readyState) {
      case "interactive":
        console.log("document.readyState: ", document.readyState, 
          `- The document has finished loading DOM. `,
          `- "DOMContentLoaded" event`
          );
        break;
      case "complete":
        console.log("document.readyState: ", document.readyState, 
          `- The page DOM with Sub-resources are now fully loaded. `,
          `- "load" event`
          );

          const container = document.querySelector("pv-container");
          const observer  = new MutationObserver(() => container.querySelectorAll("#pv-content-img").forEach(e => wheelzoom(e)));
          observer.observe(container, { childList: true });
          break;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe the container and when a new element pops in, you can search inside that container for the image and just call wheelzoom on it.

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => { 
    const container = document.getElementById("pv-container");
    const observer  = new MutationObserver(() => 
        container.querySelectorAll("#pv-content-img").forEach(e => 
            wheelzoom(e)));
    observer.observe(container, { childList: true });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I get the following error sadly:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (wheelzoom_start.js:18:20)

I tried to execute the script after the load-event of the page, but I still get that error.

Comment: Maybe you must wrap the whole thing into a onload event. This could be the reason why container is not a node at execution time.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I add the onLoad-event if I can't change the DOM? I can only add Scripts in the Header-tag. I try to run it at document.readyState=complete (see my edit to my question from Nov, 15th, but that still doesn't work sadly

Comment: I've updated the answer with an onload wrapper.

Comment: Thank you so so so much - I took your new code, but sadly I still get the error :(

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at wheelzoom_start.js:6:12

You can check it "live" here: https://archiv.wurmweb.at/Nickelsdorf/Kirche%20Katholisch/Nickelsdorf%20-%20KircheKath%20-%201790-1826%20Heiratsbuch/

Comment: Oh yes! I see the mistake. It must be the id! `const container = document.getElementById("pv-container");` Answer updated.